# Dynamic scrollbar taking data from parse server

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want dynamic scrollbar where data from the parsing server is fetched and added to the layout. So I created the dynamic linear layout and added text view and image view in it that worked fine unless I used parse server. When I am using parse server, the properties which I am adding to the text view and image view is not applied.
Here is my code

```
      LinearLayout root;
     ParseFile image;
     String shopnamestring;

    root= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addshoplinearlayout);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query= ParseQuery.getQuery("Shops");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e== null && objects.size()>0)
            {int i=0;
                for(ParseObject object: objects)
                {
                    final ImageView shopimage []= new ImageView[objects.size()];
                    final TextView shopname[]= new TextView[objects.size()];
                    final LinearLayout child[] = new LinearLayout[objects.size()];
                      child[i]= new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                    child[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams linearparams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    child[i].setLayoutParams(linearparams);
                      shopimage[i]=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                      shopname[i]= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    shopname[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams nameparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    image= (ParseFile)object.get("image");
                    shopnamestring= (String) object.get("Name");
                    shopname[i].setText(shopnamestring);
                    final int finalI = i;
                    image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                            shopimage[finalI].setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    });
                    shopimage[i].setMaxHeight(300);
                    shopimage[i].setMaxWidth(300);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageparams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    imageparams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
                    shopimage[i].setLayoutParams(imageparams);
                    shopimage[i].setClickable(true);

                    child[i].addView(shopimage[i]);
                    child[i].addView(shopname[i]);
                    root.addView(child[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to use RecyclerView instead of LinearLayout.